# VSCode test explorer displays nothing

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

I recently uninstalled Test Explorer UI extension in VSCode. After I installed it back on, the extension panel displays nothing. I performed the installation again several times with the same result:
[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEUBg.png)

And this is my settings.json file:
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
"."
],
"python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
"python.testing.unittestArgs": [
"-v",
"-s",
".",
"-p",
"test_*.py"
]

I don't think that this matters to anything but I mention that running tests from terminal works fine. Also there is no error whatsoever.

I have been looking for a solution for almost a week now and the only question that was similar to mine was this [How to get test explorer to work for Python VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981758/how-to-get-test-explorer-to-work-for-python-vs-code) but the solution here was to change "python.unitTest. to python.testing." but as you can see, mine is configure correctly.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Because the edit queue is full, I just want to mention that [this](https://ibb.co/xM1VrtX) is how the Test Explorer is supposed to look.

Comment: Is it valid to reinstall pylance or rollback the version?